# drawRect appropriate for animation code?

Tags: ios, uiview

I put animation code in drawRect in my UIView subclass. I was really looking for something like UIViewController's viewWillAppear. But I wanted to use a UIView rather than UIViewController. I am using the code below. Is it appropriate to put animation code in drawRect? The animation is just a startup animation when the view is shown.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    [_graphView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0 + (_defaultArray.count * STEP_X), self.frame.size.height)];
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(30.0 + (_defaultArray.count * STEP_X), _graphView.frame.size.height)];

    float delayInSeconds = 0.25f;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        if (_graphView.frame.size.width > GRAPH_WIDTH) [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_graphView.frame.size.width - GRAPH_WIDTH, 0.0f) animated:YES];

    });
}
```

Comment: IMHO, animation code does not belong in `drawRect`. That routine should just have the code necessary to draw the view at any given period of time. If you want to do complex animation, I do that elsewhere (and employ a `CADisplayLink` or repeating `NSTimer`).

Comment: No, drawRect should be used to draw *one frame* of your animation, while a `CADisplayLink` should be used to repeatedly update the values and redraw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a terrible idea. The only thing you should do in an implementation of `-drawRect:` is to *draw the contents of the view*. None of your code is doing anything close to that.

(If this view is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, you probably shouldn't be overriding `-drawRect:` at all.)

That code looks like it would be more appropriate in a view controller, or perhaps in the view's setup code (does it create _graphView itself?).  Without knowing more about the rest of the code, it's hard to suggest exactly where it belongs.